# Remove Category slug from link

Tags: url-rewriting, plugin-polylang

I'am using Polylang in my wordpress site, so I have too language `en` and `fr`. I set `en` as a default languge. And I create a category named `organized-trips` in `en` and `voyages-organises` in `fr`. But when I go tho this link `www.exemple.com/organized-trips` I can see all the post, but in the french link `www.exemple.com/fr/voyages-organises` it redirect to 404 page. and when I do this `www.exemple.com/fr/category/voyages-organises` it work. How I can use the first link in french without `category` slug ?

Comment: the URL `www.exemple.com/organized-trips` is a page or you have a plugin to create this special URL ?

Comment: it just a category name.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/fv-top-level-cats/) or try this trick:

[image]

Please notice the trick may not work in the future.
via [wpmudev](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/removing-category-base-urls-wordpress/)

Comment: thanks,I have already try this solution, but it not work,